# What is this green number on my Mystic Ally's icon?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I summon a Mystic Ally with my Monk, it has a green '1' in the bottom left of its icon graphic:

[image]

Surely it's not the amount of Mystic Ally's that I have summoned, because you can only summon 1 at a time, so I'm not sure what it represents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The green number displayed on your Mystic Ally *is* the number of allies summoned.

Comment: Is it possible to get more somehow then?

Comment: Not specific to the mystic ally. WD might have 3 or more zombie dogs, so the number changes accordingly.

Comment: @Bora Hmm.. Seems a bit slack on the developers' part to not change the UI slightly in these cases but I guess it's for consistency... Just makes it confusing if you haven't played the WD (which I haven't).

Comment: @MartyWallace Slightly Off-topic: You gotta try WD! It is ridiculously fun.

Comment: you can have more than 1 ally with the crudest boots and innas mantra set